# PHP Multiple Session Variables, ACCESSING EMPTY sESSION ON LOGIN CHECK

Tags: php, security, session, authentication

ok, so by now, i have spend no joke, 1 week figuring out this, finally narrowed it down to multiple session variables being created, where only 1 is the one with the data i need and the rest are empty. sopposedly session_regenerate_id(true) should have taken care of it, but only partially, with it i get 3 session vars, without it i get 6.

here is the code, hoping you wise and experience folks might illuminate me so as to how to fix this.
this is my login main, where i input credentials

```
    <?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();


if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'in';
} else {
    $logged = 'out';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Seguro: Log In</title>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
            echo '<p class="error">Error en el Inicio de Sesion!</p>';
        }
        ?> 
        <form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">                      
            Usuario: <input type="text" name="Usuario" />
            Password: <input type="password" 
                             name="password" 
                             id="password"/>
            <input type="button" 
                   value="Login" 
                   onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" /> 
        </form>

<?php
        if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
                        echo '<p>Actualmente Logueado ' . $logged . ' as ' . htmlentities($_SESSION['username']) . '.</p>';

            echo '<p>¿Cambiar de Usuario? <a href="includes/logout.php">Log out</a>.</p>';
        } else {
                        echo '<p>Actualmente Logueado ' . $logged . '.</p>';
                        echo "<p>Si no cuentas con Login, Favor de <a href='register.php'> Registrase </a></p>";
                }
?>      
    </body>
</html>
```

which redirects to process_login

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
#php debugging
#Start buffering the output. Not required if output_buffering is set on in php.ini file
#get a firePHP variable reference
#php debuggin
sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.


if (isset($_POST['Usuario'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $Usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
    $Contraseña = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.
    if (login($Usuario, $Contraseña, $mysqli) == true) {
        header('Location:../protected_page.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');

    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

which in turn redirects to protected page

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
 sec_session_start();      
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Protected Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
            <p>
                This is an example protected page.  To access this page, users
                must be logged in.  At some stage, we'll also check the role of
                the user, so pages will be able to determine the type of user
                authorised to access the page.
            </p>
            <p>Return to <a href="index.php">login page</a></p>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p>
                <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

using the functions of this login file, which work as intended, which has a custom secure session start, which might be the one causing the problem

```
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php';

function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = true;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id(true) // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}

function login($Usuario, $Contraseña, $mysqli) {


    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT RFC, Usuario, Contrasena 
        FROM empleado
       WHERE Usuario = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $Usuario);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($RFC, $username, $db_password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($RFC, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted. We are using
                // the password_verify function to avoid timing attacks.                         
                if ($Contraseña==$db_password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $RFC = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $RFC);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $RFC;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $db_password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO registo_login(user_id, Tiempo)
                                    VALUES ('$RFC', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function checkbrute($RFC, $mysqli) {
    // Get timestamp of current time 
    $now = time();

    // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours. 
    $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Tiempo 
                             FROM registro_login 
                             WHERE RFC = ? 
                            AND Tiempo > '$valid_attempts'")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $RFC);

        // Execute the prepared query. 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // If there have been more than 5 failed logins 
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
                        $_SESSION['username'], 
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
        filelog("yay");

        $RFC = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Contrasena 
                                      FROM empleados 
                                      WHERE RFC = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$RFC" to parameter. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $RFC);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($Contraseña);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $Contraseña . $user_browser);

                if (hash_equals($login_check, $login_string) ){
                    // Logged In!!!! 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in 
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in 
        return false;
    }
}

function esc_url($url) {

    if ('' == $url) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $url = (string) $url;

    $count = 1;
    while ($count) {
        $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
    }

    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

    $url = htmlentities($url);

    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
    $url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

    if ($url[0] !== '/') {
        // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        return '';
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}

function filelog($data){
    $myfile = fopen("mylog.txt", "w");
    fwrite($myfile,$data+"\r\n");
    fclose($myfile);
    return;
}
```

i really would appreciate some help, additionally i am running this on xampp, with apache server, on localhost and tried it on firefox and chrome, resulting in the same issue.

Comment: I only see 3 `$_SESSION[...] = ` assignments in the code. how could you expect to get 6 items in $_SESSION if you only assign 3?

Comment: i think i did not explain myself with enough clarity, i mentioned that i noticed, if i dont use regenerate_session_id, i get 6 $_SESSION, using it, generates 3, but i only need 1, the one with data, not the empty ones, and whenever i reach protected page, with correct credentials, isset(...) fails because one of the empty $_SESSION is being opened, in short, either kill the remaining 2 empty and finally stay with the one true session var i need, or find the way to open the correct one.

Comment: you mean you have 6 different session cookies? there's only ever ONE $_SESSION array.

Comment: in the C:\xampp\tmp, which is the default path to store the sessions, whenerver i run it, as it is now, at least, 3 files get created, of names like **"sess_us35cio0c8mclaq49h9k9e7sd3"**, basically one for every time i call a **session_start()** of which 2 are empty, and only 1 has the right data, 1 is created in the index page, 1 in process login, and 1 in protected page. when they are suppose to get deleted to only have one with **session_regenerate_id(true);**